# MariaDB shows warnings instead of errors

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB version: `10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal`

SQL:

```
insert ignore into `step` (is_draft, created_by) values ('1', 2);
```

Got warnings:

```
MariaDB [kite]> show warnings\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1364
Message: Field 'course_id' doesn't have a default value
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1364
Message: Field 'title' doesn't have a default value
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1452
Message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kite`.`step`, CONSTRAINT `step_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

I'm expecting to have an error if a constraint fails. In fact, it used to, but not now. How to enable errors instead of warnings?

Googled about SQL_MODE and tried different combinations, but no luck:

```
MariaDB [kite]> SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       @@SQL_MODE: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
@@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Looks like the problem is in `ignore` keyword. If I remove - it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want errors instead of warnings, then don't use `ignore`.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-ignore/ says:

> By using the `IGNORE` keyword all errors are converted to warnings, which will not stop inserts of additional rows.

Comment: But I need to use the `ignore` keyword for avoiding duplicates. In postgres I can do `on conflict do nothing`.

Comment: Well then enjoy your warnings instead of errors. That's what `ignore` does.

Comment: It is strange, that the `ignore` keyword has double sence: ignoring errors and using as `on conflict do nothing`.

Comment: The documentation is clear: "all errors are converted to warnings." If you want to handle each type of error differently, then run without `ignore`, and handle errors yourself in code.

Comment: I don't complain about the doc, just about the logic :)

Comment: @KirillZhirnov "The logic" is simple - either error or not. `IGNORE` converts all errors to warnings. If you want only duplication errors to be ignored then use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which is an analog of ON CONFILCT in PostgreSQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html